# Loop through each cell in a range

Tags: vba, excel, optimization

I've got a basic understanding of how VBA works. I was hoping someone could help shorten this. You will see quickly that the code is massive and would love it if I could get it optimized for my project.

```
Sub Delete_missing_vals()

Dim myLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row
myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop through range
For i = 1 To myLastRow
If Cells(i, "A").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "A").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "A").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "A"), Cells(i, "A")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "B").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "B").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "B").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "B"), Cells(i, "B")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "C").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "C").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "C").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "C")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "D").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "D").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "D").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "D"), Cells(i, "D")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "E").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "E").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "E").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "E"), Cells(i, "E")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "F").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "F").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "F").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "F"), Cells(i, "F")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "G").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "G").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "G").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "G"), Cells(i, "G")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "H").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "H").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "H").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "H"), Cells(i, "H")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "I").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "I").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "I").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "I"), Cells(i, "I")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "J").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "J").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "J").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "J"), Cells(i, "J")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "K").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "K").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "K").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "K"), Cells(i, "K")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "L").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "L").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "L").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "L"), Cells(i, "L")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "M").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "M").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "M").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "M"), Cells(i, "M")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "N").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "N").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "N").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "N"), Cells(i, "N")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "O").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "O").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "O").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "O"), Cells(i, "O")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "P").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "P").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "P").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "P"), Cells(i, "P")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "Q").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "Q").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "Q").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "Q"), Cells(i, "Q")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "R").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "R").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "R").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "R"), Cells(i, "R")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "S").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "S").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "S").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "S"), Cells(i, "S")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "T").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "T").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "T").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "T"), Cells(i, "T")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "U").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "U").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "U").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "U"), Cells(i, "U")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "V").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "V").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "V").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "V"), Cells(i, "V")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "W").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "W").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "W").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "W"), Cells(i, "W")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "X").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "X").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "X").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "X"), Cells(i, "X")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "Y").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "Y").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "Y").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "Y"), Cells(i, "Y")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "Z").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "Z").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "Z").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "Z"), Cells(i, "Z")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AA").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AA").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AA").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AA"), Cells(i, "AA")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AB").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AB").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AB").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AB"), Cells(i, "AB")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AC").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AC").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AC").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AC"), Cells(i, "AC")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AD").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AD").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AD").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AD"), Cells(i, "AD")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AE").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AE").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AE").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AE"), Cells(i, "AE")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AF").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AF").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AF").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AF"), Cells(i, "AF")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AG").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AG").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AG").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AG"), Cells(i, "AG")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AH").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AH").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AH").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AH"), Cells(i, "AH")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AI").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AI").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AI").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AI"), Cells(i, "AI")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AJ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AJ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AJ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AJ"), Cells(i, "AJ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AK").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AK").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AK").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AK"), Cells(i, "AK")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AL").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AL").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AL").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AL"), Cells(i, "AL")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AM").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AM").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AM").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AM"), Cells(i, "AM")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AN").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AN").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AN").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AN"), Cells(i, "AN")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AO").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AO").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AO").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AO"), Cells(i, "AO")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AP").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AP").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AP").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AP"), Cells(i, "AP")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AQ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AQ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AQ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AQ"), Cells(i, "AQ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AR").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AR").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AR").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AR"), Cells(i, "AR")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AS").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AS").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AS").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AS"), Cells(i, "AS")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AT").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AT").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AT").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AT"), Cells(i, "AT")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AU").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AU").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AU").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AU"), Cells(i, "AU")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AV").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AV").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AV").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AV"), Cells(i, "AV")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AW").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AW").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AW").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AW"), Cells(i, "AW")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AX").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AX").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AX").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AX"), Cells(i, "AX")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AY").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AY").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AY").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AY"), Cells(i, "AY")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "AZ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "AZ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "AZ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "AZ"), Cells(i, "AZ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BA").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BA").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BA").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BA"), Cells(i, "BA")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BB").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BB").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BB").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BB"), Cells(i, "BB")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BC").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BC").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BC").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BC"), Cells(i, "BC")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BD").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BD").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BD").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BD"), Cells(i, "BD")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BE").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BE").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BE").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BE"), Cells(i, "BE")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BF").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BF").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BF").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BF"), Cells(i, "BF")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BG").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BG").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BG").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BG"), Cells(i, "BG")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BH").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BH").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BH").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BH"), Cells(i, "BH")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BI").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BI").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BI").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BI"), Cells(i, "BI")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BJ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BJ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BJ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BJ"), Cells(i, "BJ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BK").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BK").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BK").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BK"), Cells(i, "BK")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BL").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BL").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BL").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BL"), Cells(i, "BL")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BM").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BM").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BM").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BM"), Cells(i, "BM")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BN").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BN").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BN").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BN"), Cells(i, "BN")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BO").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BO").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BO").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BO"), Cells(i, "BO")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BP").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BP").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BP").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BP"), Cells(i, "BP")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BQ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BQ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BQ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BQ"), Cells(i, "BQ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BR").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BR").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BR").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BR"), Cells(i, "BR")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BS").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BS").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BS").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BS"), Cells(i, "BS")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BT").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BT").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BT").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BT"), Cells(i, "BT")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BU").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BU").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BU").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BU"), Cells(i, "BU")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BV").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BV").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BV").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BV"), Cells(i, "BV")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BW").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BW").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BW").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BW"), Cells(i, "BW")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BX").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BX").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BX").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BX"), Cells(i, "BX")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BY").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BY").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BY").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BY"), Cells(i, "BY")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "BZ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "BZ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "BZ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "BZ"), Cells(i, "BZ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CA").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CA").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CA").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CA"), Cells(i, "CA")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CB").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CB").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CB").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CB"), Cells(i, "CB")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CC").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CC").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CC").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CC"), Cells(i, "CC")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CD").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CD").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CD").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CD"), Cells(i, "CD")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CE").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CE").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CE").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CE"), Cells(i, "CE")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CF").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CF").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CF").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CF"), Cells(i, "CF")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CG").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CG").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CG").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CG"), Cells(i, "CG")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CH").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CH").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CH").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CH"), Cells(i, "CH")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CI").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CI").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CI").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CI"), Cells(i, "CI")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CJ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CJ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CJ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CJ"), Cells(i, "CJ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CK").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CK").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CK").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CK"), Cells(i, "CK")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CL").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CL").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CL").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CL"), Cells(i, "CL")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CM").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CM").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CM").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CM"), Cells(i, "CM")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CN").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CN").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CN").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CN"), Cells(i, "CN")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CO").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CO").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CO").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CO"), Cells(i, "CO")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CP").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CP").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CP").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CP"), Cells(i, "CP")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CQ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CQ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CQ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CQ"), Cells(i, "CQ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CR").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CR").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CR").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CR"), Cells(i, "CR")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CS").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CS").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CS").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CS"), Cells(i, "CS")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CT").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CT").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CT").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CT"), Cells(i, "CT")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CU").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CU").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CU").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CU"), Cells(i, "CU")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CV").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CV").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CV").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CV"), Cells(i, "CV")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CW").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CW").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CW").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CW"), Cells(i, "CW")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CX").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CX").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CX").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CX"), Cells(i, "CX")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CY").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CY").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CY").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CY"), Cells(i, "CY")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "CZ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "CZ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "CZ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "CZ"), Cells(i, "CZ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DA").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DA").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DA").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DA"), Cells(i, "DA")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DB").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DB").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DB").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DB"), Cells(i, "DB")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DC").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DC").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DC").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DC"), Cells(i, "DC")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DD").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DD").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DD").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DD"), Cells(i, "DD")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DE").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DE").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DE").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DE"), Cells(i, "DE")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DF").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DF").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DF").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DF"), Cells(i, "DF")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DG").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DG").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DG").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DG"), Cells(i, "DG")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DH").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DH").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DH").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DH"), Cells(i, "DH")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DI").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DI").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DI").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DI"), Cells(i, "DI")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DJ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DJ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DJ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DJ"), Cells(i, "DJ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DK").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DK").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DK").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DK"), Cells(i, "DK")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DL").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DL").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DL").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DL"), Cells(i, "DL")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DM").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DM").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DM").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DM"), Cells(i, "DM")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DN").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DN").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DN").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DN"), Cells(i, "DN")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DO").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DO").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DO").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DO"), Cells(i, "DO")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DP").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DP").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DP").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DP"), Cells(i, "DP")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DQ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DQ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DQ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DQ"), Cells(i, "DQ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DR").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DR").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DR").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DR"), Cells(i, "DR")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DS").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DS").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DS").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DS"), Cells(i, "DS")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DT").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DT").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DT").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DT"), Cells(i, "DT")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DU").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DU").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DU").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DU"), Cells(i, "DU")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DV").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DV").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DV").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DV"), Cells(i, "DV")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DW").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DW").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DW").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DW"), Cells(i, "DW")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DX").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DX").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DX").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DX"), Cells(i, "DX")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DY").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DY").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DY").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DY"), Cells(i, "DY")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "DZ").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "DZ").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "DZ").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "DZ"), Cells(i, "DZ")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "EA").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "EA").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "EA").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "EA"), Cells(i, "EA")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "EB").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "EB").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "EB").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "EB"), Cells(i, "EB")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "EC").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "EC").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "EC").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "EC"), Cells(i, "EC")).ClearContents
If Cells(i, "ED").Value = -99 Or Cells(i, "ED").Value = -77 Or Cells(i, "ED").Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, "ED"), Cells(i, "ED")).ClearContents
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use another loop for the column inside the row loop?

Comment: I don't know much about VBA lol I've only been teaching myself how to do it from Friday and I'm stuck at this point, been trying all day to optimize it.

Comment: @Hosey93 Kudos to you for learning VBA, though for future reference, Code Review may be a more sutiable place, as they help improve already working code ... http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions

Comment: @Mr.Burns (and Hosey93) the Question needs to be edited and better formed for Code Review, take a look at the [How to Ask](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page of Code Review before posting over there, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this?  In case the number of columns needed changes, this will find the last column in the contiguous block.

```
Sub Delete_missing_vals()
  Dim myLastRow As Long, myLastCol as Long
  Dim i As Long, j as long

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  '   Find last row & col
  myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  myLastCol = Cells(1,"A").End(xlToRight).Column

  '   Loop through range
  For i = 1 To myLastRow
    For j = 1 to MylastCol
      If Cells(i, j) = -99 Or Cells(i, j) = -77 Or Cells(i, j) = -66 Then 
        Cells(i, j).ClearContents
      End If
    Next j
  Next i

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get it right you are Testing all columns from *A* to *ED* in ascending order. That makes 5x26+4=134 columns in ascending order.

Just create another loop in your row-loop, looping from 1 to 134.

```
For i = 1 To myLastRow
    For j=1 to 134
        If Cells(i, j).Value = -99 Or Cells(i, j).Value = -77 Or Cells(i, j).Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i, j), Cells(i, j)).ClearContents
    Next j
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick.  You could do something similar to calculating your last row to calculate the last column if needed.

```
Sub Delete_missing_vals()

    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop through range
    For i = 1 To myLastRow
        For j = 1 To 134
            If Cells(i, j).Value = -99 Or Cells(i, j).Value = -77 Or Cells(i, j).Value = -66 Then Cells(i, j).ClearContents
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Delete_missing_vals()

    Dim myLastRow   As Long
    Dim i           As Long
    Dim myVariant       as Variant

    set myVariant = Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","ETC")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'   Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'   Loop through range
    For i = 1 To myLastRow
        for col = lbound(myVariant) to Ubound(myVariant)
            If Cells(i, myVariant(col)).Value = -99 Or Cells(i,  myVariant(col)).Value = -77 Or Cells(i, myVariant(col)).Value = -66 Then Range(Cells(i,  myVariant(col)), Cells(i,  myVariant(col))).ClearContents

        next col
    next i


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

But there are probably other better ways to make it work. Still, you can select the columns manually in the array, which is a formidable bonus :)

Comment: Thanks mate, tried it and is a great alternative solution to what I had.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with this:

```
Sub Delete_missing_vals()


Dim cell As Range
Dim myRange As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set myRange = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

For Each cell In myRange

    With cell
        If .Value = -99 Or .Value = -77 Or .Value = -66 Then

            .ClearContents

        End If
    End With

Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may be able to do that by iterating all cells in your Used Range.  This is similar to Tackgnol's answer

```
Sub IterateSheetCells()
Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
        With cell
            If .Value = -99 OR .Value = -77 OR .Value = -66 Then
                .ClearContents
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```